# Search for the date of today in a Word doc filled with dates

Tags: vba, date, search, ms-word

I have Word doc filled with dates of several years. I would like to add a macro that searches today. The format of the date is DD.MM.YYYY. I tried many things in vain. The last thing I tried was:

```
Sub Today
    Dim c As String
    Set c = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY")
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

But it does not work...

Comment: Have you tried `Datetime.Now` instead of `Now`?

Comment: This question shows a woeful lack of serious research. If you'd attempted searching the date using Word's built-in Find functionality and recorded that in a macro you'd have had the beginnings of a useful code basis. "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. You need to detail HOW it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure you're getting an error message and which line is generating it. Record the Find macro for the current date. Click EDIT below your question and subsitute that code. Then ask how it can be adjusted to find "today's date" for any day and we can help you.

Comment: You declare c as String, but then use Set to assign a values: Set is only used when assigning values to object-type variables.

Comment: Make habit of break mode and use `Msgbox` to display results so that you can know where the problem is.

Comment: What You want to do after find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you are looking for?

```
Sub Demo123()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim s As String
s = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY")
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = s
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
      .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
      'or do whatever you want
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, Rahul

You helped me see the way. I eventually came up with this, which does the trick. To answer your side question, after Find it just had to go there.

```
Sub Today()
Dim s As String
s = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY^p")
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = s
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    If Selection.Find.Found Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    MsgBox "Date not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

All the best,

Willem

Comment: Thanks again, Rahul. I didn't notice the accept-function before. I have accepted.